# Git branch --merged branches not showing up

Tags: git, gitlab

I am trying to get a list of branches merged inot master. Here is a visual from GitLab:

[image: Part of graph]

I used `git fetch --prune` to update my local repository and then use `git branch --merged master` to see what branches were merged into master. As shown in the image, there is one. The output for `git branch --merged master` is `* master`. Why is this?

Comment: I don't see a branch there. I see _revisions_ that might have been developed in branches but the branches are gone. Remember that in git branches are just pointers to revisions that can be moved around at will (including deleting them)... oh, and welcome to SO!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As shown in the image, there is one

No there isn't.

**Thing to know:** A branch in Git is just a name: the name of some *one commit*.

Okay, so... There is only one branch in your image: master.

The green railroad siding is not a branch. It may have been formed historically by making commits on another branch and later merging that other branch to master; but that other branch (name) was deleted later, and no record of it remains, though of course the commits and topology do remain, and that's what you now see.

All of that is totally normal and correct. Don't worry, be happy.

---

What your image does display is at least one *merge commit*. You could find those with `git log --merges`.

Comment: ... and in fact `git branch --merged` is often used to find branch names you can delete because you know their histories are reachable from the branch they were merged in to, so why clutter the local name space?